# Connect wifi access points with Windows Native Wifi Functions

Tags: windows, winapi, wifi

Windows provides Win32 Native Wifi Functions, but when I used WlanConnect to connect a access point what needs password, it will show a tip on the notification area. If I clicked the tip, the password input dialog will show.

How can I show the password input dialog directly without click the tip on the notification area?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706274%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to specify a profile. Try the [WPA-Personal Profile Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370029(VS.85).aspx)